# Dropdown list don't stay expanded, difficult to select options in IE8

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, css, internet-explorer-8

I have one from on my web application(this site is created in ASP.NET 2.0)  in that I have used dropdownlist for country selection. I am facing issue with this in dropdownlist.
When I opened this form page in IE8 browser but it is working fine in Chrome and Fire fox, it has following issue.
i. Don't stay expanded : When clicking on dropdown list.
ii. due to first issue not able to select any option from dropdownlist.

Can any one suggest me the solution for this?

Below is the code that is rendering on IE8 browser

```
<select name="p$lt$ctl05$ContentPagePlaceHolder$p$lt$ctl03$editabletext$ucEditableText$widget1$ctl00$viewBiz$ctl00$BestTimetoCall$dropDownList" class="DropDownField" id="p_lt_ctl05_ContentPagePlaceHolder_p_lt_ctl03_editabletext_ucEditableText_widget1_ctl00_viewBiz_ctl00_BestTimetoCall_dropDownList" sizzle-1386927025787="[object Object]">

 <OPTION selected value=Morning>Morning</OPTION> 
 <OPTION value=Afternoon>Afternoon</OPTION> 
 <OPTION value=Evening>Evening</OPTION>

 </select>
```

Comment: default select dropdownlist stay open, so obviously you are doing something we are not aware of, post your relevant code!

Comment: I have added code which is rendering on IE8 browser

Comment: It looks like maybe sizzleJS is causing your problem (based on the `sizzle-{id}` attribute on your select tag).  Does the problem persist if you remove sizzleJS?